# PayPal Express Checkout Email Notifications

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, express-checkout

I have setup the PayPal express API buttons but it seems when i make a payment all goes through successfully however, from the seller side i am not receiving any emails telling me i have received a payment or such. I looked at the email notifications on the developer site there is nothing being sent out.

Am i doing something incorrectly or does the express checkout not send emails.

My integration is similar to this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/auth-capture/#

Thanks

Comment: Give more details of your implementation. What is your final API response when the payment is executed/captured/completed?

Comment: @PrestonPHX I get the expected response as shown in the doc from them all, the buyer does receive the email saying youve "authorised a payment to xxx" but on the seller side i get nothing. I accept a full payment or a deposit if its full payment its captured straight after its authorised.

Comment: Well that's not a log of the full API response, so I can only guess at what your issue might be

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the sandbox Business account receiving the payment has a confirmed email in the sandbox environment.

1. Log into it at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email
2. Send the confirmation from there, if necessary
3. Read and proceed with the confirmation, via https://developer.paypal.com/developer/notifications